# Find calls to a specific function in C (parser)

Tags: c, parsing, grep, function-call

Is there a **reliable** way to find in which places a specific function is called and their arguments in a c source file?

Currently, I use the following code.

```sh
fns=$(cat $1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*function_name(//p'|cut -f1,2 -d, --output-delimiter=' '| tr -d \")
```

This works pretty well but it is not stealthy: it will report incorrect results if my regex is matched in comments, strings, macros, if my function is called on multiple lines, ...)

Is there a robust way to solve my solution?

--

Note: I try to stay away from custom parsers as they require to handle a surprisingly high amount of corner case to work so I guess it is not the smartest way to solve my issue.

Comment: [ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) [GLOBAL](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Did you try to generate a cross reference by the linker, and use that? In the end, it should know which calls it resolved. However, this does not work for module-local calls as these are resolved immediately by the compiler.